# How to upload >5GB file using multipart API of S3 right from the browser?

Tags: web, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, multipartform-data

I have tried the PUT request by XMLHttpRequest. There is a browser-side limitation that doesn't allow me to upload files larger than 2GB. Then I have tried the POST request from an HTML form that doesn't require Javascript side preprocessing. It has 5GB upload size limitation in a single operation.

AWS recommended multipart upload in larger upload scenarios. That requires files to chunk down then upload into pieces. How to do it right from the browser, when the file size is greater than 10GB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS SDK Presigned URL + Multipart upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799982/aws-sdk-presigned-url-multipart-upload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use chucks in combination with signed URLs. See this link for more details https://github.com/prestonlimlianjie/aws-s3-multipart-presigned-upload.